# alterações em tabelas vinculadas (CASCADE etc...)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Estou aprendendo MYSQL por minha conta devido a restrição de ensino que há em minha cidade e suas proximidades, por isso gostaria de uma informação sobre como usar o CASCADE na tabela que tenho com essa estrutura:

tblUsuario
idu int not null auto_increment pk
nome

tblTelefoneN
idt int not null auto_increment pk
tipotel int not null //identificador para dizer se é celular etc.
numerotel varchar(15)

tblRelacaoUsuTel
idu int not null
idt int not null

Minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

1. A tabela de relação pelo que entendi até o momento vai pegar uma informação única em duas outras tabelas, usuario e telefone, então tenho duas Foreign Keys que se referenciam a outras Primary Keys correto?
2. Ao fazer o registro principal depois de ler em um fórum que em uma transação temos N rotinas, eu criei uma para cada inserção de telefone (4 campos de telefone, utilizando Lazarus IDE [estilo Delphi]), então tenho um INSERT INTO... para cada telefone e estou inserindo manualmente os dados na tabela tblTelefoneN e tblRelacaoUsuTel, uso o LAST_INSERT_ID() para essa 'gambiarra'.
3. Como proceder com a atualização, li sobre o CASCADE e como ele faz alterações 'vinculadas', posso usar o CASCADE de alguma forma  no meu caso? (já que o id usuário não muda) ou deveria mudar somente o campo onde tem o número do telefone no tblTelefoneN e o tipo dele?

Agradeço as respostas e a compreensão.

Comment: 1 Correto 2 XX 3 Nao tenho certeza do seu caso mas creio que não o CASCADE é usado para garatir uma integridade entre as tabelas conforme o caso , deletar , não permitir a deleção ou alteração para chave não existente , deletar/alterar em "cascata"